# Selinux is denying access to mysqld

Tags: shell, permissions, rhel, mysql, selinux

I have a script that dumps a mysql database. It then compresses the file and this gets stored in my home folder by using cron. The problem is I seem to be getting an error message.

> mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show fields from `auth_group`': Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_151e_0.MYI' (Errcode: 13) (1)
>   c2duo_db-22072011.sql

Now on my centos server graphical end, it says selinx has denied access to mysqld. Ofcourse if I disable selinux this works fine. *But I need selinux enabled.* Is there a way around this problem?

**cron**

```
10 11 * * 5 /home/sh/mysqlbackup.sh
```

**mysqlbackup.sh**

```
  #!/bin/sh

    mysqldump -uroot -ppassword --opt c2duo_db > /home/sh/c2duo_db-`date +%d%m%Y`.sql

    cd /home/sh
    tar -zcvf c2duo_db.tgz *.sql
```

**EDIT:** Here what I get from the command `grep mysqld /var/log/audit/audit.log | tail | audit2why`.

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1311581788.889:12363): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=22102 comm="mysqld" path="/tmp/#sql_151e_0.MYI" dev=dm-0 ino=103481390 scontext=root:system_r:mysqld_t:s0 tcontext=root:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 tclass=file
        Was caused by:
                Missing or disabled TE allow rule.
                Allow rules may exist but be disabled by boolean settings; check boolean settings.
                You can see the necessary allow rules by running audit2allow with this audit message as input.
```

Also, my mysql server was already installed on this machine. So I guess it is an official repo.

Comment: There are many possible causes of, and thus solutions to this problem. Please add more information to your question: how was mysql-server installed (compiled or official repo)? What is the output of `grep mysqld /var/log/audit/audit.log | tail | audit2why`? (requires policycoreutils-python and auditd)

Comment: `You can see the necessary allow rules by running audit2allow with this audit message as input.` Have you tried this ?

Comment: Obviously problem was caused with `/tmp`, what user you use to run `mysqldump` ?

Comment: I recommend you to install: setroubleshoot-server. It would reformat audit log into human language event which would appear in /var/log/messages.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have bad file context on `/tmp` directory. Show us `ls -ldZ /tmp`.

How is it possible that temporary file inside `/tmp` has `httpd_sys_content_t` fcontext?

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1311581788.889:12363): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=22102 comm="mysqld" path="/tmp/#sql_151e_0.MYI" dev=dm-0 ino=103481390 scontext=root:system_r:mysqld_t:s0 tcontext=root:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 tclass=file
        Was caused by:
                Missing or disabled TE allow rule.
                Allow rules may exist but be disabled by boolean settings; check boolean settings.
                You can see the necessary allow rules by running audit2allow with this audit message as input.
```

On RHEL it is:

```
ls -ldZ /tmp
drwxrwxrwt. root root system_u:object_r:tmp_t:s0       /tmp
```

For sure it has nothing to do with path for your backup file. If it would be permission problem, you would get something like this:

```
# su -s /bin/bash nobody -c 'mysqldump -uroot -p123456 --opt test > /root/test-`date +%d%m%Y`.sql'
bash: /root/test-13112013.sql: Permission denied
```

You can use `strace -f -ff -o /tmp/strace mysqldump -uroot -ppassword --opt c2duo_db` to see, which files it tries to open, use...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something might be mislabeled. Have you tried running `restorecon -R /var/lib/mysql`?

Comment: Actually `restorecon -R /tmp` would be better.

Answer (score -1):

I just run the command suggested by `audit2why` :

```
% echo "type=AVC msg=audit(1311581788.889:12363): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=22102 comm="mysqld" path="/tmp/#sql_151e_0.MYI" dev=dm-0 ino=103481390 scontext=root:system_r:mysqld_t:s0 tcontext=root:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 tclass=file" | audit2allow
```

This command returns :

```
#============= mysqld_t ==============
allow mysqld_t httpd_sys_content_t:file write;
```

This is probably the SeLinux policy allow rule what you need.

But I don't know if allow this rule is safe ...

Comment: Could you please show a 'ls -lZd /tmp', please?

Comment: This rule is definitely not safe.

Comment: Can you explain why ?

Comment: It allows MySQL to write to all of your web site content, which it has absolutely no possible legitimate reason for.

Answer (score -1):

**Reason behind the issue:**

The reason behind the issue is that you have placed the shell script file inside "/home/sh/"

It seems like /sh/ folder which resides under /home/ folder is not a system generated folder (one created while creating system user), instead you have created it manually. So when the cron runs the system restricts access to the scripts inside the shell script file.

**Note:** In linux access is restricted to the files which resides inside /home/ directory. But the files residing under **/home/[directory created by system for each system user]/** has unrestricted access

**Solution:**

```
Move the /sh/ folder along with the sh file inside a system generated folder under /home/ directory (or) create a system user named sh
```